# What can I do to increase the performance of a Lua program?

Tags: performance, optimization, lua

I asked a question about Lua perfromance, and on of the [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124455/how-do-you-pre-size-an-array-in-lua#152894) asked:

> Have you studied general tips for keeping Lua performance high? i.e. know table creation and rather reuse a table than create a new one, use of 'local print=print' and such to avoid global accesses.

This is a slightly different question from [Lua Patterns,Tips and Tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89523/lua-patternstips-and-tricks) because I'd like answers that specifically impact performance and (if possible) an explanation of why performance is impacted.

One tip per answer would be ideal.

Comment: <a href="http://lua-users.org/wiki/OptimisationTips">Lua Optimization Tips</a>

Comment: http://trac.caspring.org/wiki/LuaPerformance

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In response to some of the other answers and comments:

It is true that as a programmer you should generally avoid premature optimization. *But*. This is not so true for scripting languages where the compiler does not optimize much -- or at all.

So, whenever you write something in Lua, and that is executed very often, is run in a time-critical environment or could run for a while, it is a good thing to know things to *avoid* (and avoid them).

This is a collection of what I found out over time. Some of it I found out over the net, but being of a suspicious nature when *the interwebs* are concerned I tested all of it myself. Also, I have read the Lua performance paper at Lua.org.

Some reference:

- [Lua Performance Tips](http://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf)
- [Lua-users.org Optimisation Tips](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OptimisationTips)

## Avoid globals

This is one of the most common hints, but stating it once more can't hurt.

Globals are stored in a hashtable by their name. Accessing them means you have to access a table index. While Lua has a pretty good hashtable implementation, it's still a lot slower than accessing a local variable. If you have to use globals, assign their value to a local variable, this is faster at the 2nd variable access.

```
do
  x = gFoo + gFoo;
end
do -- this actually performs better.
  local lFoo = gFoo;
  x = lFoo + lFoo;
end
```

(Not that simple testing may yield different results. eg. `local x; for i=1, 1000 do x=i; end` here the for loop header takes actually more time than the loop body, thus profiling results could be distorted.)

## Avoid string creation

Lua hashes all strings on creation, this makes comparison and using them in tables very fast and reduces memory use since all strings are stored internally only once. But it makes string creation more expensive.

A popular option to avoid excessive string creation is using tables. For example, if you have to assemble a long string, create a table, put the individual strings in there and then use `table.concat` to join it *once*

```
-- do NOT do something like this
local ret = "";
for i=1, C do
  ret = ret..foo();
end
```

If `foo()` would return only the character `A`, this loop would create a series of strings like `""`, `"A"`, `"AA"`, `"AAA"`, etc. Each string would be hashed and reside in memory until the application finishes -- see the problem here?

```
-- this is a lot faster
local ret = {};
for i=1, C do
  ret[#ret+1] = foo();
end
ret = table.concat(ret);
```

This method does not create strings at all during the loop, the string is created in the function `foo` and only references are copied into the table. Afterwards, concat creates a second string `"AAAAAA..."` (depending on how large `C` is). Note that you *could* use `i` instead of `#ret+1` but often you don't have such a useful loop and you won't have an iterator variable you can use.

Another trick I found somewhere on lua-users.org is to use gsub if you have to parse a string

```
some_string:gsub(".", function(m)
  return "A";
end);
```

This looks odd at first, the benefit is that gsub creates a string "at once" in C which is only hashed after it is passed back to lua when gsub returns. This avoids table creation, but possibly has more function overhead (not if you call `foo()` anyway, but if `foo()` is actually an expression)

## Avoid function overhead

Use language constructs instead of functions where possible

### function `ipairs`

When iterating a table, the function overhead from ipairs does not justify it's use. To iterate a table, instead use

```
for k=1, #tbl do local v = tbl[k];
```

It does exactly the same without the function call overhead (pairs actually returns another function which is then called for every element in the table while `#tbl` is only evaluated once). It's a lot faster, even if you need the value. And if you don't...

**Note for Lua 5.2**: In 5.2 you can actually define a `__ipairs` field in the metatable, which *does* make `ipairs` useful in some cases. However, Lua 5.2 also makes the `__len` field work for tables, so you might *still* prefer the above code to `ipairs` as then the `__len` metamethod is only called once, while for `ipairs` you would get an additional function call per iteration.

### functions `table.insert`, `table.remove`

Simple uses of `table.insert` and `table.remove` can be replaced by using the `#` operator instead. Basically this is for simple push and pop operations. Here are some examples:

```
table.insert(foo, bar);
-- does the same as
foo[#foo+1] = bar;

local x = table.remove(foo);
-- does the same as
local x = foo[#foo];
foo[#foo] = nil;
```

For shifts (eg. `table.remove(foo, 1)`), and if ending up with a sparse table is not desirable, it is of course still better to use the table functions.

## Use tables for SQL-IN alike compares

You might - or might not - have decisions in your code like the following

```
if a == "C" or a == "D" or a == "E" or a == "F" then
   ...
end
```

Now this is a perfectly valid case, however (from my own testing) starting with 4 comparisons and excluding table generation, this is actually faster:

```
local compares = { C = true, D = true, E = true, F = true };
if compares[a] then
   ...
end
```

And since hash tables have constant look up time, the performance gain increases with every additional comparison. On the other hand if "most of the time" one or two comparisons match, you might be better off with the Boolean way or a combination.

## Avoid frequent table creation

This is discussed thoroughly in [Lua Performance Tips](http://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf). Basically the problem is that Lua allocates your table on demand and doing it this way will actually take more time than cleaning it's content and filling it again.

However, this is a bit of a problem, since Lua itself does not provide a method for removing all elements from a table, and `pairs()` is not the performance beast itself. I have not done any performance testing on this problem myself yet.

If you can, define a C function that clears a table, this should be a good solution for table reuse.

## Avoid doing the same over and over

This is the biggest problem, I think. While a compiler in a non-interpreted language can easily optimize away a lot of redundancies, Lua will not.

### Memoize

Using tables this can be done quite easily in Lua. For single-argument functions you can even replace them with a table and __index metamethod. Even though this destroys transparancy, performance is better on cached values due to one less function call.

Here is an implementation of memoization for a single argument using a metatable. (Important: This variant does *not* support a nil value argument, but is pretty damn fast for existing values.)

```
function tmemoize(func)
    return setmetatable({}, {
        __index = function(self, k)
            local v = func(k);
            self[k] = v
            return v;
        end
    });
end
-- usage (does not support nil values!)
local mf = tmemoize(myfunc);
local v  = mf[x];
```

You could actually modify this pattern for multiple input values

### [Partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)

The idea is similar to memoization, which is to "cache" results. But here instead of caching the results of the function, you would cache intermediate values by putting their calculation in a constructor function that defines the calculation function in it's block. In reality I would just call it clever use of closures.

```
-- Normal function
function foo(a, b, x)
    return cheaper_expression(expensive_expression(a,b), x);
end
-- foo(a,b,x1);
-- foo(a,b,x2);
-- ...

-- Partial application
function foo(a, b)
    local C = expensive_expression(a,b);
    return function(x)
        return cheaper_expression(C, x);
    end
end
-- local f = foo(a,b);
-- f(x1);
-- f(x2);
-- ...
```

This way it is possible to easily create flexible functions that cache some of their work without too much impact on program flow.

An extreme variant of this would be [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), but that is actually more a way to mimic functional programming than anything else.

Here is a more extensive ("real world") example with some code omissions, otherwise it would easily take up the whole page here (namely `get_color_values` actually does a lot of value checking and recognizes accepts mixed values)

```
function LinearColorBlender(col_from, col_to)
    local cfr, cfg, cfb, cfa = get_color_values(col_from);
    local ctr, ctg, ctb, cta = get_color_values(col_to);
    local cdr, cdg, cdb, cda = ctr-cfr, ctg-cfg, ctb-cfb, cta-cfa;
    if not cfr or not ctr then
        error("One of given arguments is not a color.");
    end

    return function(pos)
        if type(pos) ~= "number" then
            error("arg1 (pos) must be in range 0..1");
        end
        if pos < 0 then pos = 0; end;
        if pos > 1 then pos = 1; end;
        return cfr + cdr*pos, cfg + cdg*pos, cfb + cdb*pos, cfa + cda*pos;
    end
end
-- Call 
local blender = LinearColorBlender({1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,1});
object:SetColor(blender(0.1));
object:SetColor(blender(0.3));
object:SetColor(blender(0.7));
```

You can see that once the blender was created, the function only has to sanity-check a single value instead of up to eight. I even extracted the difference calculation, though it probably does not improve a lot, I hope it shows what this pattern tries to achieve.

Comment: Nicely done.  I'm not 100% sure I understand the "Function constructors" section.  It might be because the math doesn't seem to have any real meaning.  Can you provide an actual example?  But otherwise, this is an outstanding list and well worth noodling over.

Comment: @JonEricson thank you for the feedback, I renamed the last section to "Parametrized functions" which I believe is a better name, as I wasn't happy with it either.

Comment: "Use tables for SQL-IN alike compares" -- In my opinion, the opposite should be suggested, use conditionals as often as possible to avoid table creation unless the lookup table is persistent or if it's just a one-time thing.

Comment: @Alundaio Obviously a static `if` construct with many OR's should be replaced by a persistent table, creating the table on each function call would defeat the purpose. I guess my example could be misinterpreted to mean it should be constructed each time. I'll try to find the time to fix it, thank you!

Comment: Also there is `local function ...`.

Comment: @Cloudiness true, but it is implicit in the very first section "avoid globals" since functions are just another type of value in Lua.

Comment: @dualed Though you used global/environment fields to put functions in the examples ;)

Comment: @Cloudiness If you mean that I have not put a `local` in front of every named function definition in my examples: I remember going back and forth on that decision, but there are valid use-cases for using globals and those examples are not about variable scope. (holy... I wrote this 5 years ago :))

Answer (score 10):

If your lua program is really too slow, use the Lua profiler and clean up expensive stuff or migrate to C.  But if you're not sitting there waiting, your time is wasted.

The first law of optimization: Don't.

I'd love to see a problem where you have a choice between ipairs and pairs and can measure the effect of the difference.

The one easy piece of low-hanging fruit is to remember to use local variables within each module.  It's general not worth doing stuff like

```
local strfind = string.find
```

unless you can find a measurement telling you otherwise.

Comment: Are you working for MS? It seems they took your "law" to heart, considering that Notepad noticeably stutters on hardware more powerful that entire military and space control complex of roughly 30 years ago.

Comment: yes I know, and it is abused to create slow software to hell and back. Maybe it works for Don himself who can always assert what needs optimizing and what not. For 90% programmers out there it reads as "regardless how slow your stupid algorithm is, don't optimize it ever". That's why I don't like when it is propagated.

Comment: This is legitimately the most useless answer I have ever seen on this website and yet perfectly fine questions get downvoted to hell.

Answer (score 4):

- Making the most used functions locals
- Making good use of tables as HashSets
- Lowering table creation by reutilization
- Using luajit!

Answer (score 2):

It must be also pointed that using array fields from tables is much faster than using tables with any kind of key. It happens (almost) all Lua implementations (including LuaJ) store a called "array part" inside tables, which is accessed by the table array fields, and doesn't store the field key, nor lookup for it ;).

You can even also imitate static aspects of other languages like `struct`, C++/Java `class`, etc.. Locals and arrays are enough.

Answer (score 1):

Keep tables short, the larger the table the longer the search time.
And in the same line iterating over numerically indexed tables (=arrays) is faster than key based tables (thus ipairs is faster than pairs)

Comment: Lua lua tables are a combination of arrays and hastables, accessing either part by index has constant time complexity (`O(1)`).

Comment: O(1) hides a constant k. It k they are talking about here.

Comment: @Stomp if k is constant, the size of the table does not matter. This is what I am talking about.