# Trying to make function which takes string as input and returns no. of words in whole string

Tags: lua

**It takes Input as a string such as this - 'Nice one'
And Output gives - 4,3 (which is no. Of words in sentence or string)
**

```
function countx(str)
   local count = {}
   for i = 1, string.len(str) do
       s = ''
       while (i<=string.len(str) and string.sub(str, i, i) ~= ' ' ) do
           s = s .. string.sub(str, i, i)
           i = i+1
       end
       if (string.len(s)>0) then
           table.insert(count,string.len(s))
       end
   end
   return table.concat(count, ',')
end
```

Comment: There are 2 words in 'Nice one'. I think you mean  "output the length of the words in the string".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```lua
-- Localise for performance.
local insert = table.insert

local text = 'I am a poor boy straight. I do not need sympathy'

local function word_lengths (text)
    local lengths = {}
    for word in text:gmatch '[%l%u]+' do
        insert (lengths, word:len())
    end
    return lengths
end

print ('{' .. table.concat (word_lengths (text), ', ') .. '}')
```

- `gmatch` returns an iterator over matches of a pattern in a string.
- `[%l%u]+` is a Lua regular expression (see http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial) matching at least one lowercase or  uppercase letter:

  - `[]` is a *character class*: a set of characters. It matches anything inside brackets, e.g. `[ab]` will match both `a` and `b`,
  - `%l` is any lowercase Latin letter,
  - `%u` is any uppercase Latin letter,
  - `+` means one or more repeats.

Therefore, `text:gmatch '[%l%u]+'` will return an iterator that will produce words, consisting of Latin letters, one by one, until `text` is over. This iterator is used in generic `for` (see https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html); and on any iteration `word` will contain a full match of the regular expression.

Comment: That is exactly what I want but what is use of [%l%u]+ I didn't understand what you said about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a simple alternative with your new requirements:

```
function CountWordLength (String)
  local Results  = { }
  local Continue = true
  local Position = 1
  local SpacePosition
  
  while Continue do
    SpacePosition = string.find(String, " ", Position)
    if SpacePosition then
      Results[#Results + 1] = SpacePosition - Position
      Position = SpacePosition + 1
      -- if needed to print the string
      -- local SubString = String:sub(Position, SpacePosition)
      -- print(SubString)
    else
      Continue = false
    end    
  end

  Results[#Results + 1] = #String - Position + 1
  
  return Results  
end

Results = CountWordLength('I am a boy')

for Index, Value in ipairs(Results) do
  print(Value)
end
```

Which gives the following results:

```
1
2
1
3
```

Comment: I want to count characters in word in whole string and string passes from the user such as user pass. 'I am a boy' then it's gives 1,2,1,3 according to characters in words.

Comment: I updated one more time, basically it's doing what you asked. The code is probably efficient because it does not create intermediate strings or useless data. You can read more information regarding performances, especially table.insert, if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154672/what-can-i-do-to-increase-the-performance-of-a-lua-program

Answer (score 0):

```
def countLenWords(s):
   s=s.split(" ")
   s=map(len,s)
   s=map(str,s)
   s=list(s)
   return s
```

The above functions returns a list containing number of characters in each word

`s=s.split(" ")` splits string with delimiter " " (space)
`s=map(len,s)` maps the words into length of the words in int
`s=map(str,s)` maps the values into string
`s=list(s)` converts `map` object to `list`

Short version of above function (all in one line)

```
def countLenWords(s):
   return list(map(str,map(len,s.split(" "))))
```

Comment: I want to count characters in word in whole string and string passes from the user such as user pass. 'I am a boy' then it's gives 1,2,1,3 according to characters in words.

Comment: @Dxx Return value as a string or a list ? Modified answer to return as list